# Finding and saving present directory of a SAS-Studio-program in a Linux server

Tags: linux, sas, sas-macro, sas-studio

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make a macro variable in SAS Studio which saves the "present working directory" as a macro variable.

The SAS-program is run in a "`CPF`" process flow file in SAS Studio, and the whole SAS-file and processes are saved and run in a Linux server.

In SAS-Studio, the location of CPF-process flow file seems like in the directory `/sasdata/model_v1`, and when I run a Linux command like `X "pwd"` then I expect that the result will give `/sasdata/model_v1`, but I get another directory instead like `/sasinstall/sasconfig/Lev1/SASApp` instead, I guess the the process flow file with `CPF`-suffix is run from this directory.

So the question is how I can find and save the working directory of my `cpf`-file and save as a macro-variable, or even maybe for my other sas-files too, I may need the solution for both SAS-files and CPF-files.

If I find the directory, then I guess it should be enough to save them as macro-variable by using `%let macrovariable = "/directory"`

Comment: Please provide more detail on your environment. What version of SAS/Studio? What version of SAS? Are you opening the CPF file in the SAS/Studio interface and submitting it?  Or does SAS/Studio support submitting the CPF file in the background from a source file like it does when running a regular SAS program?

Comment: @Tom it is SAS Studio release 3.6 (enterprise edition). SAS release: 9.04.01M4P11092016. SAS platform: Linux LIN X64 3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64.
And yes, I open the CPF-file in SAS-Studio interface and I submit the SAS-commands in this interface.
I add a screenshot to show how the CPF-file is located. It seems like physically it is located under `/sasdata/...` but the command `X "pwd"` gives the directory `/sasinstall/...` instead

Comment: The current directory of the SAS process will just be the current directory from when the SAS workspace server process was launched. Change your settings in SAS/Studio so that your log shows what SAS/Studio submitted as lines 1 to 60 and check if it has set any macro variables that contain the path or filename. That is your only hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think SAS will show you the path of the process file. It doesn't in SAS/Studio 3.5.

It will set the path for a normal program file (as long as you have saved it) in the _SASPROGRAMFILE macro variable.

Comment: it is very pity that there is no automated solution. I need to manage the historical versions of the model manually, and my plan was creating a copy of the model under another map and SAS would recognize the new map automatically without changing the macro variables, but it seems like it is not possible.